# How to download large file quickly in Qt

Tags: qt

How do I download a large file in chunks parallelly in Qt. So that the file download time is reduced.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are using QNetwork and the download is an HTTP GET you will need to do the following:

1. Use a HEAD request to get the file size ([`Content-Length`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)) and check the server supports Range requests ([`Accept-Ranges`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5))
2. [Enable pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) on the GET requests
3. Set the [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header based on the size of the content

To enable HTTP pipelining on your requests by setting the [`HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) attribute:

```
QNetworkRequest req(url);
req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
```

Set the range headers:

```
req.setRawHeader("Range", "bytes=0-499");
```

Comment: I tried to find out file size using the below code but no luck. Please let me know what is wrong with it.
 QNetworkAccessManager * mngr = new QNetworkAccessManager();
 QNetworkRequest rqst(url);
 QNetworkReply *rply = mngr->head(rqst);
 int length = rply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toInt();

Comment: The request is non-blocking, you need to wait for the `QNetworkAccessManager::finished` or `QNetworkReply::finished` (or `QNetworkReply::metaDataChanged` for GET) signal before you can access the HTTP headers. Please read the [documentation for QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details) or have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt_using_QNetworkAccessManager,_QNetworkRequest,_QNetworkReply).

Comment: When I specify a wrong url (e.g: "http://10.70.22.200:8080/Install_T.msi" instead of "http://10.70.22.200:8080/Install_Test.msi" ), the header size shows some value (in this case 990) {size = replyy->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toLongLong();} When I specify wrong URL, i expected the header to be zero since the file does not exist. Thus I am not able to verify whether file exists, before proceeding with file download.

Comment: Your server is probably generating a 404 page that contains a message explaining the file is missing. You can use the program [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to craft queries and view the response when debugging, e.g: `curl -v "http://10.70.22.200:8080/Install_T.msi"`

Comment: Yes you were right.. server is generating a 404 page containing page missing message. So how do I test whether it is an error message or small sized file is available at specified location. Sincere Thanks for all your quick responses.

Comment: Check [`QNetworkReply::error()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#error). Please read the documentation, it is there to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10422/discussion-between-user1111-and-skyhisi)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that answer? It seems that my server is not always using pipelining (I am download an Azure blob file) and I wonder why. More specifically, why do we need to set the Range and how it is used under the hood would help (I cannot find anything in Qt doc). With the azure API it is advised to use "x-ms-range" instead to support large files.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstand your post, should the parallelisation with several chunks be done on client side (meaning range should be a subset of the complete range)? Or is Qt going to split the request in several?

Comment: @CanardMoussant The Range header is used to request a range (subset) of bytes from a file. Qt will not automatically chunk the request. Your client would use a HEAD request to find the total size of the file, then based on the number of parallel downloads calculate the file ranges for each download and start the simultaneous downloads with the range request. Your client would be responsible for merging the downloaded chunks into wherever it needs to go (file, database, etc).

Comment: Yes I managed to do that at end, but I forgot to come back here and confirm. Thanks!